# MVC + WCF + EF - File stream post - The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC application, I am using a [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) control to allow users to upload a file from their local system to the SQL database.

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var name = Request.Files[0].FileName;
                var size = Request.Files[0].ContentLength;
                var type = Request.Files[0].ContentType;
var fileStream = Request.Files[0].InputStream;
 byte[] documentBytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
                fileStream.Read(documentBytes, 0, documentBytes.Length);

                Documents databaseDocument = new Documents
                {
                    FileContent = documentBytes,
                    DocumentName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(name),
                    DocumentSize = size,
                    DocumentType = type
                };                               
                bool result = this.updateService.SaveDocument(databaseDocument);
            }
```

"updateService" is actually a reference to the WCF service.
I get the error on the "SaveDocument" call in above code.
I have set uploadReadAheadSize (in applicationHost.config), and maxReceivedMessageSize (in WCF and Web configuration files) as suggested on other forums.
Still this error is not resolving for me.

This gives an error saying "The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large "

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889947/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-413-request-entity-too-large-wcf?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a stream as parameter to your service operation if you don't want to have issues with transmitting too large objects.

Service interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IStreamedService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void PrepareUpload(long fileLength, string fileName);
    [OperationContract]
    void UploadFile(Stream fileStream);
}
```

Service implementation:

```
public class StreamedService : IStreamedService
{
    private static long lengthOfFile;
    private static string nameOfFile;

    public void PrepareUpload(long fileLength, string fileName)
    {
        lengthOfFile = fileLength;
        nameOfFile = fileName;
    }

    public void UploadFile(Stream fileStream)
    {
        if(lengthOfFile==0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameOfFile)) 
            throw new ArgumentException("Upload must be prepared");
        var bytes = new byte[lengthOfFile];
        var numberOfBytesToRead = bytes.Length;
        var numberOfReadBytes = 0;

        while (numberOfBytesToRead > 0)
        {
            var n = fileStream.Read(bytes, numberOfReadBytes, numberOfBytesToRead);
            if (n == 0)
                break;
            numberOfReadBytes += n;
            numberOfBytesToRead -= n;
        }

        var fsOut = new FileStream(string.Format(@"c:\temp\{0}", nameOfFile), FileMode.Create);
        fsOut.Write(bytes, 0, numberOfReadBytes);
        fsOut.Close();
    }
}
```

Service config:

```
system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="StreamedService.StreamedService">
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:60000/StreamedService"
      binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" contract="Contracts.IStreamedService" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NewBinding0" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" />
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Client implementation:

```
    var proxy = new ChannelFactory<IStreamedService>("MyEndpoint").CreateChannel();
    var fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\FileToUpload.zip", FileMode.Open);
    proxy.PrepareUpload(fs.Length, "uploadedFile.zip");
    proxy.UploadFile(fs);
```

Client config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NewBinding0" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" />
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:60000/StreamedService"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
            contract="Contracts.IStreamedService" name="MyEndpoint">
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The above works with basicHttpBinding as well. And you could of course use a MemoryStream on the server side instead of a FileStream, and then deserialize it to some entity that you want to save to a DB.